# NSURLDownload resumeData nil

Tags: objective-c

I've written an download tool. It's working fine with NSURLDownload.
But when it comes to resuming downloads I have some problems. The resumeData is always nil!
When I download the same files with jDownloader, stop the download and resume again, jDownloader resumes the download! So is is possible with this files and the server!

code:

```
- (void)startDownload {
    status = @"loading";
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    urlDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [urlDownload setDeletesFileUponFailure:NO];

    if (!urlDownload) {
        [self error:@"Failed starting download request!"];
    }
}
```

test:

```
- (IBAction)stopWithResumeOption:(id)sender {
    [urlDownload cancel];
    NSData *tempData = [urlDownload resumeData];

    NSLog(@"%@",tempData);
}
```

If I stop the download while loading with "stopWithResumeOption" I get always nil!
Am I missing something?!

Edit:

What info does the resumeData return at all? If it is only the length of the already downloaded data or something, maybe I can create this resumeData by myself?! Anyone tried this before?

Edit 2:

Here is the response header of one file I'm trying to resume:

```
{
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 43346723;
    "Content-Type" = "application/pdf";
    Date = "Sun, 13 Mar 2011 13:08:44 GMT";
    Etag = 1185n;
    Pragma = public;
    Server = dbws;
    "X-Robots-Tag" = "noindex,nofollow";
}
```

Even an ETag is provided by the server!

Is there a chance to do it this way:

```
- (IBAction) resume:(id)sender {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%llu-%llu",bytesReceived, totalBytesToLoad]; 
    [request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];  

    urlDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

But I'm not sure how to go on with this try...

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> **cancel**
>
> Cancels the receiver’s download and deletes the downloaded file.

Consider simulating the failure by disconnecting from the network instead. Don't forget to implement the delegate methods.

**EDIT:**

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/Reference/Reference.html) also says:

> **resumeData**
>
> Returns nil if the download is not able to be resumed.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Resume data will only be returned if the protocol of the download as well as the server support resuming

Are you certain that the server supports resuming?

**EDIT 2:**

Make sure `urlDownload` is not `nil` in your `stopWithResumeOption:` method..

`urlDownload` is `assigned` in your `startDownload` method (how is it declared?)

Try:

```
urlDownload = [[[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] retain];
```

and remember to `[urlDownload release]` where appropriate.

Comment: but this didn't solve the problem! The resumeData is nil, even if I try it with a connection failure! I read that the download needs to be canceled, to get the resumeData!!??

Comment: Yes, like I said, I tried this with jDownloader! And with different servers, netload and dropbox for example.

Comment: Edited answer. suspect that `urlDownload` is being released after it fails which should show up as a leak.

Comment: Tested it, urlDownload is not nil! (by the way, it is an instanz variable, defined in the .h file). I really have no idea why it doesn't work! Is it possible that the NSURLDownload object doesn't support resuming at all!? (have never read that anyone having the same problem solved it). Or is there any other way to resume a download?!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but hopefully this will save someone some time.

As of now, this is not mentioned in the documentation, but the **resumeData property always returns nil unless the download is cancelled or fails**.

Seems unfortunate since this makes it difficult to resume downloads should your app crash in the middle of a download.